# Error occurs running code in terminal "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object"

Tags: python

```py
def ran_keys(issue1,issue2=None):
    ran_number = random.sample(data.keys(), 1)
    for i in ran_number:
        val1 = data.get(i)
    n3, s3, t3, r3 = val1
    if issue1 == r3:
        return val1
    else:
        if Counter == 1:
            ran_keys(first_issue,second_issue)
        elif Counter == 2:
            ran_keys(first_issue)


def random_mode():
    if Counter == 1:
        vall = ran_keys(first_issue,second_issue)
        name3, s3, t3, r3 = vall
        if r3 == first_issue or second_issue:
            print('Random selected agent available for your issue = \n')
            print('{:<15}  {:<15}  {:<15}  {:<15}'.format('Name', 'Availability', 'Available Since', 'Role'))
            print('{:<15}  {:<15}  {:<15}  {:<15}'.format(name3, s3, t3, r3))
        else:
            print('No agent found for your issue..........\nTry Again..................')
            main1()
    elif Counter == 2:
        vall = ran_keys(first_issue)
        name3, s3, t3, r3 = vall
        if r3 == first_issue:
            print('Random selected agent available for your issue = \n')
            print('{:<15}  {:<15}  {:<15}  {:<15}'.format('Name', 'Availability', 'Available Since', 'Role'))
            print('{:<15}  {:<15}  {:<15}  {:<15}'.format(name3, s3, t3, r3))
        else:
            print('No agent found for your issue..........\nTry Again..................')
            main1()
```

This code gives me an error when I run it on terminal. The error is :

```
  File "C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/python_class/project/addCopy.py", line 295, in modes
    random_mode()
  File "C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/python_class/project/addCopy.py", line 264, in random_mode
    name3, s3, t3, r3 = vall
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

but when I run it on Python console, it works perfectly fine

Note: **The code given above is a part of code so some variables wouldn't be present here.**

Comment: `ran_keys` can reach the end of the function and return `None`

Comment: Maybe you meant it to propagate the return value when it recurses, e.g. instead of `ran_keys(first_issue)` to have `return ran_keys(first_issue)` and similarly for the other recursive call.

Comment: i dont know, but when same thing is run on python console it works fine

Comment: Do you want to `name3, s3, t3, r3` all these variables to have the same values as `vall` or you want `vall` to store all these variables as a list or tuple??

Comment: By the way, the line `if r3 == first_issue or second_issue:` is almost certainly not what you intend. `if r3 in (first_issue, second_issue):` is far more likely.

Comment: `vall` variable get value as a list , which contains 4 different values, so using different variable I store those value in `name3, s3, t3, r3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function `ran_keys` returns val1 `if issue1 == r3`, but there is no return statement in your `else` condition, try:

```
def ran_keys(issue1,issue2=None):
    ran_number = random.sample(data.keys(), 1)
    for i in ran_number:
        val1 = data.get(i)
    n3, s3, t3, r3 = val1
    if issue1 == r3:
        return val1
    else:
        if Counter == 1:
            return ran_keys(first_issue,second_issue)
        elif Counter == 2:
            return ran_keys(first_issue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright I have finally understood what you want to do..

Use dictionary it will be helpful.

```py
vall = ['Name', 'time','availability','role']

values = [name3, s3, t3, r3]

dictionary = zip(vall,values)
dictionary = dict(dictionary)
```

Comment: i guess you did not understand me correctly, I meant `vall  = ['Name', 'time','availability','role']`, therefore I store these in variables `name3, s3, t3, r3.`

Comment: What do you want to do with `name3, s3, t3, r3.` . What are you storing in them.. The error is with the line `name3, s3, t3, r3. = vall` as you aren't making it clear whether you want `name3, s3, t3, r3.` to store values of `vall` or want `vall` to store values of `name3, s3, t3, r3.` as a iist.

Comment: Was this what you wanted ??

Comment: `vall` variable is already a list, and I want to store the values of that list in these variables and then compare them with issues if it matches I'll print it.

Comment: `vall  = ['Name', 'time','availability','role']` and you want `'Name' ` to have the values of 'name3' and so on right ??